Can we use leaf shutter mechanism as a drone dropping mechansim for payload weight of 3lbs?
I'm considering implementing a drone payload drop mechanism capable of handling payloads weighing up to 3lbs. I'm intrigued by the idea of using a leaf shutter mechanism for this purpose, but I haven't found any existing examples online. Before proceeding, I'd like to ascertain the feasibility of this approach for our drone project. Additionally, I'm interested in understanding the potential advantages and disadvantages of incorporating a leaf shutter mechanism into our drone design.

Should be migrated to Drones stack exchange unless "do my project for me" is off topic there

No.  Leaf shutters are designed for speed, not for supporting mechanical loads.
Instead, just put a loop on the top of the payload.  Put a pin through the loop.  Retract the pin, in your case with a cheap tiny servo.  Then the payload falls.  Simpler, more reliable, secures the payload before release, fewer parts to fail or maintain, less friction, much heavier payloads possible, and it's been used for decades -- maybe centuries if you count dropping things from kites.
